# How to authenticate SharePoint Online(Office 365) from desktop

Tags: javascript, authentication, office365, sharepoint-online

I am creating a JavaScript app which runs in browser of the desktop user, I need to display some data from SharePoint Online site, how do I authenticate and get display data in the App?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this using JavaScript. You should use the Client Object Model (CSOM) to achieve the same.

If you want to achieve the same please refer the url

https://github.com/nickvdheuvel/O365-ADALJS-examples/blob/master/Authenticate-an-Office-365-user-with-ADAL-JS/Authenticate-an-Office-365-user-with-ADAL-JS.html

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: The provided link is broken

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data did  you want to display? As far as I know, we can query the data from SharePoint online using Microsoft Graph API. To use this API, we need to register the app first and in this scenario, we can register a client app(refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest)).

Then we can use the [ADAL.JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to authenticate the application. For a sample demonstrating basic usage of ADAL JS please refer to this [repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp).

And if you were developing an [SPA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/) app, we can use the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant protocol to obtain an ID token (id_token) from Azure AD. The token is cached and the client attaches it to the request as the bearer token when making calls to its web API back end.